# Replace non-decimal in KeyUp

Tags: c#, regex

Thanks to Joey in this question [Remove non-digits, non-decimals, repeating decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077384/remove-non-digits-non-decimals-repeating-decimals). I have a `Regex.Replace`, that looks like this

```
Regex.Replace(Txt, "[^-?\d+\.]|(?<=\.[^.]*)\.", "");
```

But now I want it to only allow one comma (`,`), and the user can use either a comma or a dot, but not both

How do I implement that?

So legal numbers could be

```
2.324324
0.34345325
2,5454
0,453453
```

Comment: KeyUp? Have you considered non-keyboard methods to get text data into your control (such as pasting from the clipboard using the context menu)?

Comment: Mels Yes, I have and that is not a possibility

Comment: You should have a look at using [UIElement.PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(Txt, @"[^\d.,]|(?<=[.,][^.,]*)[.,]", "");
```